# Magento 1.9.x Order Email item not displaying randomly

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates

we have setup separate order email template for admin. For some orders it does not print order item section. Here is the code from default.phtml file responsible for item listing. It seems random so its hard to debug why its not loading for some orders.

```
/app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/email/order/items.phtml



echo  $this->getItemHtml($_item)
```

Comment: After debuging it seems like this item section is not loading only for iphone theme , Any idea what could be wrong , why it is not printing output of  $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?